# Akka on Android multiple reference.conf

Tags: android, scala, akka, proguard

I'm trying to add akka and spray to my android app (written in Scala with Scaloid lib). Everything should work fine, my ide is not throwing any errors. I found some links addressing the same problem, but nothing helped me so far. When I build my project with:

```
sbt ~android:install
```

When I have the following line in my build.sbt

```
apkbuildExcludes in Android += "reference.conf"
```

I get the error

```
08-31 08:02:45.598    7884-7884/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: at.itn.android, PID: 7884
    com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
```

without it

```
[info] Generating dex, incremental=true
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK reference.conf
    File 1: /home/markus/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.5.jar
    File 2: /home/markus/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.5.jar
```

I don't have any reference.conf (I also tried the *reference.conf* https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf )

here's my *build.sbt*

```
android.Plugin.androidBuild

name := "myApp"
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

proguardCache in Android ++= Seq(
  ProguardCache("org.scaloid") % "org.scaloid"
)

proguardOptions in Android ++= Seq(
  "-dontobfuscate",
  "-dontoptimize",
  "-dontwarn scala.collection.mutable.**",
  "-ignorewarnings",
  "-keep class scala.Dynamic"
)

apkbuildExcludes in Android += "reference.conf"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "org.scaloid" %% "scaloid" % scaloidV,
    "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % akkaV
    // ....
  )
}
```

Can someone send me in the right direction on how I can get akka running on android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a working example of using akka and spray on android. Check it out.
https://github.com/anjeikatkov/android-akka-spray-example

Hope, it helps.

Comment: thank you very much! I spent hours in figuring this problem out. With your example code I finally managed to get it working

Answer (score 1):

I have described a solution on the scala-on-android mailing list a while ago. Here’s the link: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-on-android/JwMQCtC2zCs/rHHg4BU55W0J.

TL;DR: The main issue seems to be the wrong classloader (you should see a warning in logcat). I preloaded the config in the Application:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
  ...
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  ...
}
```

And also pointed ActorSystem to the right classloader explicitly:

```
val app = getApplication.asInstanceOf[MyApplication] 
val actorSystem = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem", app.config, app.getClassLoader)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should place the "reference.conf" file from akka repostiory into **/src/main/resources** directory of your project.

Comment: that's where my reference.conf is located

Comment: so, are there akka configuration entries in your reference.conf file?  (sorry, if it sounds silly, but I've actually faced the same problem recently, and I solved it simply, as I've described above in the answer)

Comment: I didn't have any reference.conf file at first. Since I got this error I added the whole file from: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf

I don't really need any configuration right now, I just would like to get my project running with akka. How did you solve it? Any specific entries in the reference.conf?

Comment: Well, when I faced this problem (DuplicateFileException during build), I actually did the following: 1) added "reference.conf" into apkBuildExcludes in my build.scala, 2) placed "reference.conf" from akka repo to my resources dir. And also, it's understood, that the version number of akka config and the version number of akka in porject dependencies must be identical.

Comment: If it won't help, later, I can share a working minimal akka-based scaloid project with you.

Comment: I tried it again, but still the same error. I use akka v2.3.5 in my build.sbt and in my reference.conf. If you could share me a minimal akka-based project it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Only to have an complete answer:

There seems to be three kinds of directory layout that are accepted by android-sdk-plugin:

1. Ant
2. Gradle
3. Wrapped

All answers that I find says that I should put my reference.conf file on $BASE/src/main/resources/. But looking at [ProjectLayout.scala](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/master/src/ProjectLayout.scala) we can see that this advice only really works in Gradle layouts.

On my project, the plugin is using the Ant layout, so it should be put on $BASE/resources/