# Akka on Android not running (app crashes)

Tags: java, android, scala

I am trying to use akka with android. My use case is very simple and I have given the akka part of the code below.

```
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("lingua", ConfigFactory
                    .parseFile(new File("client.conf")));
            ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(MessageProcessor.class), "processor");
            txtView.setText(master.path().toString());
            master.tell("I am here", ActorRef.noSender());
        }
    });
```

My app crashes while starting. I get the following error in the log cat.

```
06-19 18:49:40.780  18477-18477/com.ngtech.akkatest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:414)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
        at com.ngtech.akkatest.AkkaActivity.onCreate(AkkaActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5252)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4954)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have solved the problems listed in the stackoverflow forums given below

[Akka on Android multiple reference.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588841/akka-on-android-multiple-reference-conf)

[Akka on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958027/akka-on-android)

but still the app crashes. I am not using scala/scaloid. I am using akka lib for java.

I have uploaded the full code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y9hiks0s0b1qji/AkkaTest.zip?dl=0)

I have added the following akka jars to the libs folder
1. akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar
2. config-1.2.1.jar
3. scala-library-2.11.5.jar

what might have gone wrong. please guide me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Looks like the error is not related to Akka, but a missing AppCompat library

Comment: I also thought so but If i remove the akka part of code it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the is issue with Library dependency, I suppose the Dependency is not given in the build.grade

Comment: It is given in the build.gradle file. else it was not compiling

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/config-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/scala-library-2.11.5.jar')
}